# Use different methods depending of the instance of the class

Tags: java

I have the following HashMap:

```java
HashMap<Integer, Object> ItemsData = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
```

In the HashMap, I have objects of various classes, such as

- ClassOne
- ClassTwo
- ClassThree

Each class has its own methods, attributes etc.
How do I refer to proper method, depending on the instance of the class?

For example:

- `ItemsData.get(5).bark()` -> because item 5 is instance of class 1 which has method bark
- `ItemsData.get(2).jump()` -> because item 2 is instance of class 2 which has method jump
- `ItemsData.get(6).fire()` -> because item 6 is instance of class 3 which has method fire

Comment: Hi there, search for "Java Factory Pattern" (it is one way to solve your problem) It will probably give you a good answer and teach you about [Software Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)

Comment: I think you need a different approach.  Maybe use a `enum` to described the "expected" types ie (BARK, JUMP, FIRE).  Then use a "manager" class which can return the required type `manager.get(Types.BARK).bark()` or just better yet, `manager.bark()` and allow it to do the dirty work internally :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally having such an untyped map in the first place is a code smell. You didn't explain enough of the underlying problem you're trying to solve to give you good advice on a nicer solution; merely to point out that this solution probably is severely suboptimal.

If you insist on using it, you can use `instanceof` to check if a value is of a certain type, and use a cast operator to treat it as a certain type:

```
Map<Integer, Object> badIdea = new ....;

...

Object secondValue = badIdea.get(1);
if (secondValue instanceof Dog) {
  Dog dog = (Dog) secondValue;
  dog.bark();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface, eg:

```
interface Actor {
    void act();
}
```

And keep a collection of those:

```
Map<Integer, Actor> ItemsData = new HashMap<>();
```

Have your classes implement `Actor`, either directly:

```
public ClassOne implements Actor {
    public void act() {
        // make a barking noise
    }
    // other fields and methods
}
```

or indirectly:

```
public ClassOne implements Actor {
    public void act() {
        bark();
    }
    public void bark() {
        // make a barking noise
    }
    // other fields and methods
}
```

Then invoke Actor's method instead of the original specific method:

```
itemsData.get(5).act();
```

You can also invoke all conveniently:

```
itemsData.forEach(Actor::act);
```

For a full discussion of this idea, read [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).